# Connection parameters for OPCUA with Basic256Sha256

Tags: java, plc, opc-ua, plc4x

I'm currently facing an issue with PLC4J OPC UA while attempting to establish an encrypted connection without using a discovery server. I've implemented the connection using the following Java code:

```
String connectionString = String.format("opcua:tcp://%s:%d?discovery=%b", host, port, discovery);
connectionString += (username.isBlank()) ? "" : String.format("&username=%s", username);
connectionString += (password.isBlank()) ? "" : String.format("&password=%s", password);
connectionString += (certDirectory.isBlank()) ? "" : String.format("&certDirectory=%s", certDirectory);
connectionString += (securityPolicy.isBlank()) ? "" : String.format("&securityPolicy=%s", securityPolicy);
connectionString += (keyStoreFile.isBlank()) ? "" : String.format("&keyStoreFile=%s", keyStoreFile);
connectionString += (keyStorePassword.isBlank()) ? "" : String.format("&keyStorePassword=%s", keyStorePassword);

try (PlcConnection connection = PlcDriverManager.getDefault().getConnectionManager().getConnection(connectionString)) {
        ...
}
```

***However, when executing this code, I encounter the following exception:***

`io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.plc4x.java.opcua.readwrite.PascalByteString.getLengthInBits()" because "this.receiverCertificateThumbprint" is null`

I have ensured that all the parameters like host, port, discovery, etc., are correctly set. It seems like an issue with the OPC UA connection, and the receiverCertificateThumbprint not being set in certain scenarios.

***Here are some additional details:***

When using security None and providing a username and password, everything works correctly.

The keystore is found and opened successfully, but the receiverCertificateThumbprint is never set.

Upon further investigation, it seems that receiverCertificateThumbprint is only set when using a discovery server. I found its usage within the `org.apache.plc4x.java.opcua.context.SecureChannel` class, specifically in the `onDiscoverGetEndpointsRequest()` method.

```
onDiscoverGetEndpointsRequest() {
    // ...
    try {
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        byte[] digest = messageDigest.digest(driverContext.getSenderCertificate());
        driverContext.setThumbprint(new PascalByteString(digest.length, digest));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to find hashing algorithm");
    }
    // ...
}
```

Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. If additional information is needed, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, please give us a few more days. A lot of work has been put into the certificate handling of the PLC4X OPC-UA driver and we hope that we will be able to merge these changes pretty soon. As soon as that's done, there will be a new release of Apache PLC4X, that should support almost all certificate types.

Comment: We have merged the changes for this yesterday and if you could give the latest 0.12.0-SNAPSHOT a try. We will be starting a new release in the next few days ... so if you spot any issues with the current solution: Now would be the time to report anything or wait for the next release.

Comment: It seems that when using the 0.12.0-SNAPSHOT version, I encounter an issue preventing me from progressing beyond the error message: "org.apache.plc4x.java.api.exceptions.PlcConnectionException: Unsupported transport tcp." I'm wondering if there have been changes to the connection string format. Thanks a lot for your support. @ChristoferDutz

Comment: Hi Marco, could you please open an issue in GitHub for that. I'm sure someone of our community will take on the task of helping you. https://github.com/apache/plc4x/issues